# How do I create a range that goes from the first row of a 2D matrix to the last row?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix that is of dimensions NX2.
I am defining a function like this:

```
def overlap_test(R):
    for i in range( )
```

I'm struggling to write the range arguments because my matrix doesn't have fixed numbers; the numbers within it are randomly generated. So I want a general way of saying from the first row to the last row of the matrix.

How do I say i want the function to iterate over the range from the first row to the nth row???
i don't know what the notation is for saying first row of matrix?

Comment: Please show your matrix.

Comment: why [tag:matlab] tag?

Comment: This is my matrix:  R=nr.unfirom(size=(n,2))

Comment: i am defining a function called overlap_test(R). Each row in my matrix is a coordinate pair. I want my function to go through each row and see if any of the co-ordinates overlap. I have two columns, but N rows. I don't know how to define the range to tell it to do this. I also don't want the function to compare the first row onto itself.

Answer (score 0):

The function  [`.shape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy.ndarray.shape)  can help you :

```
YourMatrix.shape
```

This function return a tuple (r, c), which contains the dimension of your matrix. So you can derterminate the last row of your matrix, and the range of your function for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ? :

```
for row in matrix:
    print row
    # Or do whatever u want with the row
```

Note that `matrix.shape[0]` gives you the number of rows that you have and `matrix.shape[1]` number of columns.

Comment: how do you set the first row as an argument? i don't want to select specific co-ordinates in the first row as they are changing so i want it to be general? Is R[1,0] a general way of saying the first row?

Comment: If you want to loop over the first row you can do that : `for item in matrix[0,:]:`

Comment: i'm letting i be the first column, that represents x co-ordinates. and i'm letting j be the second column of corresponding y co-ordinates. I said for i in range(R[:,0]):                                                                      for j in range(R[0,:]):         Is this a correct way for selecting both columns separately?

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in matrix:
    for column in row:
        print(column)
```

something like that maybe??

Comment: How does this solve the original poster's problem? Add some explanation, please.

Comment: He wants to iterate over every item in the 2D matrix without knowing the items that each row has. With the above 2 lines he can iterate over every item in the 2D matrix without knowing anything about the size